# How to solve bash error "syntax error at line 3: 'CYBER_UNAME=$' unexpected"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sunos

This error happens when I run a software containing bash script with beggining like this:

```
#! /bin/sh 

CYBER_UNAME=$(uname)
CYBER_UNAME_M=$(uname -m)
```

I tried to execute these two commands in terminal and it works fine. This error only happens when I run the shell script. What should I do?

The result of 'uname' is SunOS. This shell script cannot be modified since it's protected on our server.

Comment: This does not seem to be a bash script or a bash error. `#!/bin/sh` is not the same as `#!/bin/bash` on a lot of systems. Can you change how you invoke the script. Instead of invoking it directly try `bash /full/path/to/the/script`

Comment: Is this the only thing in your script? Runs fine in my terminal with output when `echo`'d

Comment: An old Sun OS could maybe be using pure bourne shell, which would require backticks instead of `$(`...`)`, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
#! /bin/sh
```

should read:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

So, that script will probably never really work.

If you cannot modify the script in situ, you might want to copy it to your local directory and correct it.

Otherwise,

```
tail +2 scriptname|/bin/bash
```

might work.